# make windows don't offer any more to send an error report

Tags: windows

I don't care if it will never send the error report (preferred) or always send it.

I just don't want it to ask me.

I am running windows-xp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Open System in the Control Panel (or right-click on the My Computer icon and select Properties.
>   Choose the Advanced tab, and click Error Reporting.
>   You can disable error reporting entirely here, or enable it selectively for certain programs.

http://www.annoyances.org/exec/show/article03-003

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to disable the Error Reporting Service too.

Start > Run > services.msc

Find "Error Reporting Service", right-click on it, go to "Properties", and set the service to "Disabled".

If you are not going to use it, might as well free up the RAM too.